# Typesetting Raphaël text node with MathJax

Tags: math, raphael, mathjax

Is it possible to add a text node to a Raphaël created SVG and typeset its math with MathJax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar came up on the [MathJax User Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/hpXzQSHwnMw/ldbopj0dq5YJ). To quote:

> MathJax doesn't render inside `<text>...</text>` inside SVG.  A `<text>` block can only contain text, so that would require MathJax to break up the `<text>` element, reposition the pieces, and insert SVG (not HTML-CSS or NativeMML) output.  It would be potentially possible using the SVG output jax, but this isn't currently supported. 
>   The `<foreignObject>` approach is the only one that currently works (except in IE9, which doesn't implement `<foreignObject>`).
>
> It is certainly a use-case to consider for future development.

Comment: Hm, I'll have to check the <foreignObject> approach. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Let us know (here or on the MathJax User Group) if you run into trouble.

Comment: In fact I run into trouble, but doesn't seem related to MathJax nor Raphaël. I have problems with <foreignObject>s, but I will open another question for that.